# SQL Server query - Correction in syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, solr-query-syntax

Could you please help me to correct the syntax ?
I have to write below code in SQL server. 
This is working perfectly fine in Oracle database.

```
Select to_number(substr((((END_TS - BEGIN_TS)*(24*60*60))),1,10)) AS EXECUTION_TIME 
from TABLE B
```

Also `END_TS` and `BEGIN_TS` are of `datetime` datatypes.

Comment: What will happen in oracle in this expression `END_TS - BEGIN_TS`

Comment: if you are `END_TS - BEGIN_TS` using this to subtract two dates, you should use [DATE_DIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) in `SQL Server`

Comment: So END_TS and BEGIN_TS are datetime columns in MySQL. Are they timestamp columns in Oracle? Additionally, did you know that this query causes an ORA-906? Are you sure you're pasting the correct text of the query into your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server math can not be performed directly on dates, as it can in Oracle.  You need to apply a [datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function to calculate the difference before you manipulate it:

```
select convert(numeric(10,9),left(datediff(second,begin_ts,end_ts)/(24.0*60*60),10)) from table;
```

Note that the expression in the divisor needs to have a floating point number in it (hence the ".0") otherwise the result is rounded to an integer.

After performing the date calculation, the [left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) function is the equivalent of the substring in Oracle. It converts to a varchar then takes the first 10 characters.  Convert then returns to a numeric, which is the equivalent of Oracle's variable-length number. It is necessary to tell convert that you expect digits after the decimal, otherwise it will round.

The substring for the first 10 characters has a bad smell, I would leave it out.  This snippet does the calculation without restricting to the first ten characters.

```
select datediff(second,begin_ts,end_ts)/(24.0*60*60) from table;
```

Also note that the Oracle version provides fractional dates. If you only wanted the whole day then use "day" as the datepart parameter to datediff.

Comment: Thanks Steven, let me execute it but how to handle that to_number ( substring (a,1,10) part ?

Comment: Edited to add the string handling, which looks like a hack to me.  I think you're better off without it.